# Display real time ads in AdMob banner

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am following this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#12) on Firebase, adding AdMob in our app. I did whatever was written.

**XML :**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Activity :**

```
    private AdView mAdView;
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**String :**

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

I am getting this message :

`09-02 02:04:53.088 26922-26939/com.arqamahmad.languageslearnandtalk W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
09-02 02:04:53.118 26922-26922/com.arqamahmad.languageslearnandtalk W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0`

Then I registered the application in AdMob, went through the steps.

But I am not seeing real time ads in the banner instead I am seeing the text shown by Firebase on the banner.

So how can we get real time ads on the banner.

PS : This is my practice app and not in the play store. Just in my personal device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 is a test ad-unit id. Replace it with your App's ad-unit id.

also change the java to

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX");
            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and copy google-service.json file you have downloaded to the root folder of your project.

Comment: It is coming blank now. In the AdMob page along with ad unit Id they have also given App Id, do I need to use that also somewhere?

Comment: wait for it.. its slow at first but later it will show... when you upload you app to the app store and link admob with you app. it will load ads faster

Comment: you only have to use the ad-unit id, which is like ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX

Comment: I mean the whole banner is just blank. So should I keep the activity open for the ad to pop up or does it come after some time due to registration and other stuffs. I mean how much time does it usually take?

Comment: it took more than a minute for me.

Comment: I think there is some problem. It is open for more than 10 minutes but it is completely blank. Is everything fine with my code?

Comment: you will find more detail through logcat

Comment: Its still blank. Do we have to make some extra changes in the AdMob registration time. I changed the code , didn't touch the XML part. What to do?

Comment: Yes I added the json file.

Comment: Everything seems fine !!

Comment: Can you see the github link?

Comment: In the plugin did you add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'` only this for ads or some firebase ads plugin also?

Comment: I have the exact same probably, it's just white, link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279476/admob-banner-not-showing-android

Comment: I am getting this message in the logcat `09-02 02:04:53.088 26922-26939/com.arqamahmad.languageslearnandtalk W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
09-02 02:04:53.118 26922-26922/com.arqamahmad.languageslearnandtalk W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0`